# How to activate all engines with a single button push?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

In Kerbal Space Program (XBox One), my son likes to design rockets with multiple boosters. However, using the controller to separately activate each engine while launching usually results in launchpad disasters.

Is there a setting that ties all of the engines together so that they can be activated with a single button push? Are there rocket components that have to be installed during assembly to make this happen?

As much as I enjoy gigantic explosions, he's rather frustrated. I'd like to be able to help him, but I can't even figure out how to google for this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When designing your rocket, put all the engines on the same stage, then press the "activate stage" button to activate them.  I haven't used the XBox version, so I don't know which buttons you'd use for this.

Keep in mind that KSP numbers the stages backwards, with stage 0 being the last one activated.  For example, with a simple suborbital rocket, stage 2 would be "fire the engines", stage 1 would be "separate the capsule from the booster", and stage 0 would be "deploy the parachute".

Answer (score 8):

[Mark’s answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/401269/1478) is the correct one, but I wanted to point out another option:

- set your throttle to zero
- activate as many engines as you would like
- set throttles to full

Note that SRBs are not throttleable after moving to the launchpad, so you will need to stage them separately at launch. This is much like the Shuttle’s launch procedure, so just think of it as a nod to historical accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Also use action groups. It enables you to customize functions for `0-9` where you can activate them at once.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/322077)

Comment: @Joachim You definitely made a mistake. Action groups provide such functionalities.

Comment: But, even though it might add useful information, I feel like it doesn't actually answer the question. And if it would, I think you'd have to elaborate: how do you go from customizing an action group to being able to activate all engines with a single button push?